# What is the best way of doing dom manipulation in angular 6 like we do with jquery or vanilla javascript

Tags: angular

Could you please share some resources from where it can be studied properly.

Comment: https://alligator.io/angular/using-renderer2/

Answer (score 0):

As a good rule of thumb for DOM manipulation in Angular:

**Don't!**

Use `ng-if` and `ng-show`/`ng-hide` in your templates instead ...

1. https://angular.io/guide/ajs-quick-reference#ng-if
2. https://angular.io/guide/ajs-quick-reference#ng-show
3. https://angular.io/guide/ajs-quick-reference#ng-hide

...  as well as `ng-repeat` and `*ngFor`!

4. https://angular.io/guide/ajs-quick-reference#ng-repeat
5. https://angular.io/guide/ajs-quick-reference#ngfor

Comment: Sorry I did not get you.

Comment: There simply is no "best way of doing DOM manipulation" in Angular 6. Doing DOM manipulation in an Angular project is very likely to be a dirty hack.